# «На ряде» или «в ряду»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, выбор-варианта

*Белые воротнички работают **на ряде** совместных предприятий.*
Почему не ***в ряду** совместных предприятий*? В чем отличие?

Answer (score 3):

1. **Использование того или иного предлога** регулируется прежде всего разным **значением предлога**. Например, я учусь в институте, но учусь на факультете журналистики. Почему так, а не иначе?

**Предлог В** характерен для структур,  имеющих какую-то внутреннюю сложную организацию  (в институте несколько факультетов, то есть внутри института),  а **предлог НА** такого значение не имеет, мы воспринимаем предмет как нечто **целостное** и тогда говорим: он работает на предприятии.

Также  «***Белые воротнички работают на ряде совместных предприятий»***.  Ряд здесь однородный,  состоит из одинаковых элементов, то есть это **целый ряд**.

2. А когда же можно сказать **«в ряду»?**  Вот пример: «*Советская спелеология сравнительно молода, однако ее достижения находятся **в ряду** самых выдающихся в мире*». Здесь достижения советской спелеологии — это только часть общих достижений этой науки, то есть ряд у нас **разнородный.**  Другими словами, он уже не целый, а имеющий внутреннюю структуру.

Можно также сказать:  ***В ряду совместных предприятий** наметились перемены: их структура стала более разнообразной.*

Comment: а "в ряде" можно говорить?

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ на комментарий**: а "в ряде" можно говорить?

Закономерный вопрос. Можно так говорить, но **в определенных сочетаниях**. Примеров в Нацкорпусе много:

«А вот сталкинг (навязчивое, нежелательное внимание к человеку) ***в ряде*** стран уже попадает под определение правонарушении». «***В ряде*** заявленных проектов такая тенденция, вероятно, сохранится и в будущем».

Также встречается: в ряде отраслей, в вряде случаев. Это предложный изъяснительный падеж (***в ряде***), но не местный (***в ряду***).

Ряд также мыслится как **однородный**  (на ряде, в ряде), но при этом различаются значения **предлогов** НА и В (сравним: в институте и на факультете). **Предлог В** говорит о наличии внутренней структуры (в ряде), а **предлог НА** подчеркивает обобщенное значение структуры (на ряде).

Язык сам выбирает **походящую форму**. Если такие формы существуют (можно проверить по Нацуорпусу), то этот факт нужно объяснить, а вот разрешать или запрещать  нежелательно.

Answer (score 1):

В этом вопросе столкнулись сразу две проблемы.

Первая: слово "ряд" — слово многозначное (можно даже сказать, глобально многозначное).
Вторая: выбор предлога в предложном падеже — **в** или **на**.

По смыслу в предложении использовано следующее значение слова [*ряд*](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4):
**5.** только ед.; предл.: **в ряде**, чего. (обычно с прил. целый). Некоторое количество чего-либо однородного, однотипного. *Накопился ряд вопросов. Рассмотрим ряд типовых случаев. Это правило имеет ряд исключений. Отстали по целому ряду причин. Напечатать ряд стихотворений молодого поэта.*

• С существительным "предприятие" в предложном падеже используется предлог **на**.
Можно выстроить цепочку:
предприятие — на предприятии; работают на предприятии — работают на ряде предприятий (= на нескольких предприятиях).

Для сравнения (другие конструкции с предлогом "на"):
выпускают на ряде фабрик, обитают на ряде островов, представлены на ряде сайтов.

Примеры:
Новинка была испытана **на ряде предприятий** электронной, часовой, авиационной промышленности... («Зеленая волна» // «Работница», 1989);
Ждали... резкого ускорения темпов строительства **на ряде предприятий**, и прежде всего на «Запорожстали» (Л. И. Брежнев. Возрождение (1980)).

• Конструкции с предлогом "в":
работают в ряде школ, обслуживаются в ряде магазинов, имеются в ряде стран.

Comment: Не озвучена первая проблема, и нет её решения. Многозначность — это не проблема. Сначала показалось, что будет об уместности использования слова "ряд", что будет интересно.

Answer (score -1):

Использование того или иного предлога регулируется прежде всего глаголом (работать на/ работать в) и его смысловым дополнением (предприятие). Собирательное слово **ряд** как будто не имеет отношения к делу и никак не регулирует тип предлога. Это слово вообще можно удалить из предложения.

```
 Они работают в ряде городов/Они работают в некоторых городах
 Они работают на ряде автобусов/Они работают на некоторых автобусах
```

Comment: К сожалению, ответ не отвечает на вопрос, так как вопрос был "в чём отличие и как правильно", то, что можно убрать, это и так ясно.